# React Bootstrap dropdown with filter doesn't work on mapped data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I'm using the `react-bootstrap` library in a project, and have used the `<Dropdown />` component, and I'm trying to get it to include a filterable search. I've got this from the docs:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';

// The forwardRef is important!!
// Dropdown needs access to the DOM node in order to position the Menu
const CustomToggle = React.forwardRef(({ children, onClick }, ref) => (
  <a
    href=""
    ref={ref}
    onClick={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      onClick(e);
    }}
  >
    {children}
    &#x25bc;
  </a>
));

// forwardRef again here!
// Dropdown needs access to the DOM of the Menu to measure it
const CustomMenu = React.forwardRef(
  ({ children, style, className, 'aria-labelledby': labeledBy }, ref) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');

    return (
      <div
        ref={ref}
        style={style}
        className={className}
        aria-labelledby={labeledBy}
      >
        <Form.Control
          autoFocus
          className="mx-3 my-2 w-auto"
          placeholder="Type to filter..."
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
          value={value}
        />
        <ul className="list-unstyled">
          {React.Children.toArray(children).filter(
            (child) =>
              !value || child.props.children.toLowerCase().startsWith(value),
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  },
);

render(
  <Dropdown>
    <Dropdown.Toggle as={CustomToggle} id="dropdown-custom-components">
      Custom toggle
    </Dropdown.Toggle>

    <Dropdown.Menu as={CustomMenu}>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="1">Red</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="2">Blue</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="3" active>
        Orange
      </Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="1">Red-Orange</Dropdown.Item>
    </Dropdown.Menu>
  </Dropdown>,
);
```

And with the default data it works, but if I replace it with some data which I map over:

```
                        <Dropdown className="mb-2">
                          <Dropdown.Toggle
                            className="form-control"
                            as={CustomToggle}
                            id="dropdown-custom-components"
                          >
                            Search for contact...
                          </Dropdown.Toggle>

                          <Dropdown.Menu as={CustomMenu}>
                            {allContacts.map((contact, key) => {
                              return (
                                <Dropdown.Item
                                  key={key}
                                  value={contact.name}
                                  onClick={(e) => {
                                    console.log(e);
                                    setSelectedContact(contact);
                                  }}
                                >
                                  {contact.name} - {contact.outlet}
                                </Dropdown.Item>
                              );
                            })}
                          </Dropdown.Menu>
                        </Dropdown>
```

It displays the data in the dropdown but if I try and search for something I get an error: `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {map, forEach, count, toArray, only}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` and this confused me because the data I'm mapping over (`allContacts`) is already an array, but it is an array of objects, if that makes a difference?

I'd appreciate any pointers, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else has the same problem, I've managed to solve it for me.

If I don't pass the `key` prop in the `map()` function, and instead use the UID of the contact, and remove the `value` attribute, it then works!